# How can a user traverse directories to a file but hide all other items while traversing subdirectories Windows server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, user-permissions

How can a user traverse folders to a file that he has rights to, but not show other files or directories that he doesn't have rights to while traversing all other directories to get to the specified file. ?  Lets say that the file is located deep in a directory tree so he has to traverse many folders to get to the file and all those folders have files and I want these files to not show, so I want the user to get to his file using the explorer. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Give the user a shortcut to the file.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now but but my boss doesn't want that. I come from Novell where you just give access to the file and can browse through all directories. thanks for your answer

Comment: I think this might technically possible by laboriously going through the ACLs at every level of the directory tree but even if that works it's likely to make a big mess of your ACLs. I would either recommend locating the file elsewhere or separately sharing the folder that directly contains the file so the user in question can just connect to the immediate folder level via that share.

Comment: I see. I could do that but it will take me some time to complete. I thought Microsoft had an easy way of doing this. Thanks tho.

Comment: There are essentially two ways of accomplishing this: `1,` By using the default `bypass traverse checking` **user right** or `2.` Using the `Traverse Folder` **NTFS permission**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving the user access to the file via a Windows Share, you can use Access Bases Enumeration (ABE). That way the user will only see shares & folders they have been given permissions to. Check the link below for an explanation.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2016/09/01/access-based-enumeration-abe-concepts-part-1-of-2/